# PayPal IPN works for sandbox but doesn't while live

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I've read so much questions and I couldn't find the right solution for my problem.

I've currently a webshop where they can pay, and if they pay I will insert it in my database, but if I try to run this code on sandbox.paypal.com it works totally fine like, I get it in the transactions table too (how I want it). But if I change it from sandbox.paypal.com to just paypal.com it doesn't work any more. Here is the code of what I do without the sandbox.

Package Page (which sends people to PayPal to pay, and I will *** out some information which shouldn't make sense though):

```
$paypalurl = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&amount=".$row['price']."&business=".$paypalemail."&item_name=".$name."&item_number=".$row['id']."&return=".$url."packages.php"."&rm=2&notify_url=**********/gateway/paypalipn.php"."&cancel_return=".$url."packages.php"."&no_note=1&currency_code=USD";

header("Location: ".$paypalurl);
```

And this is the IPN file, where the problem should be:

```
require_once('config.php');

// STEP 1: Read POST data

// reading posted data from directly from $_POST causes serialization 
// issues with array data in POST
// reading raw POST data from input stream instead. 
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
   }
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

$ch = curl_init('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'); // change to [...]sandbox.paypal[...] when using sandbox to test
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    if ($_POST['mc_gross'] != NULL)
        $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    else
        $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross1'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['payer_email']);

    echo $item_name.'<br>';
    echo $item_number.'<br>';
    echo $payment_status.'<br>';
    echo $payment_amount.'<br>';
    echo $payment_currency.'<br>';
    echo $txn_id.'<br>';
    echo $payer_email.'<br>';

    $date = time();

    $datae = explode("A8D",$item_name);
    $name = $datae[0];
    $uid = $datae[1];
    $uip = $datae[2];

    $query = "INSERT INTO transactions (uid,uip,date,payeremail,paymentstatus,package,amount,currency) VALUES ($uid,'$uip',$date,'$payer_email','$payment_status',$item_number,'$payment_amount','$payment_currency')";
    mysqli_query($con,$query);

    //After uploading in transaction checking if could find package with this id
    //Should be USD
    if($payment_currency == 'USD'){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM packages WHERE price=$payment_amount";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $package = $row['id'];
                $date = time();
                if($row['length'] > 0){
                    $length = $date + $row['length'];
                }else{
                    $length = 0;
                }
                $query2 = "UPDATE users SET rank=2,package=$package,length=$length WHERE id=$uid";
                mysqli_query($con,$query2);
            }
        }
    }

} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    die('Well.. Nice try though! But no ;(');
}
```

But I don't understand it because it does work with sandbox.paypal.com. I just have NO clue why it does work for sandbox.paypal.com but not with live PayPal version!

Comment: When it doesn't work, are there any PHP errors on your side? Do you have a control Panel in your live PayPal system, and if so does it record a failure message, or nothing at all?

Comment: You can remove the magic quotes stuff, it is no longer supported in PHP. [Read this](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).

Comment: At a guess, your two queries have SQL injection vulnerabilities in them. Use bound parameters instead. Search for "PHP MySQLi parameter binding" or similar.

Comment: I don't know if I'm getting errors to be fair, but like it should work on normal PayPal when sandbox works right? It used to work in the past till I changed from host, maybe it's because a different PHP version or something like that I have no clue..

Comment: Ah, that's something you did not mention before. You said that the code works on the sandbox PayPal but not the live one, but you did not mention that you are also swapping servers on your end as well. For your server that works on the PayPal sandbox, can you do a live transaction (e.g. for a $0.01 charge)? On the server that does not work with live PayPal, does it work with the sandbox?

Comment: With the previous host both worked fine, sandbox and live. On this host it only works for sandbox but not for the live version.

Comment: (1) What does `$res` contain after the failed operation? (2) Did you check your logs?